# Show my current node in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a issue with my jQuery side bar.

My page is reloading after each click on the side bar.
I can tag by an id which li is the current position in the menu.

But my jQuery doesn't slide down my side bar to show the current context menu.

It worked until I add a new submenu.... :(

Can somebody help me?

Thanks.

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});

$("#menu-toggle-2").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled-2");
  $('#menu ul').hide();
});

function initMenu() {
  $('#menu ul').hide();

  var test = $('[id=submenu]')
  for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    var element = test[i];
    if ($(element).children('.current').length > 0) {
      $('#tournaments ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
      $(element).parent().slideDown('normal')
    }
  }

  $('#menu ul').children('.current').parent().show();

  $('#menu li a').click(function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      return false;
    }

    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible')) && checkElement.attr("id") != "submenu") {
      $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
      checkElement.slideDown('normal');
      return false;
    }

    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible')) && checkElement.attr("id") == "submenu") {
      $('#tournaments ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
      checkElement.slideDown('normal');
      return false;
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  initMenu();
});
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
           <i class="fa fa-universal-access fa-stack-1x "></i>
        </span>
        My Compete
      </a>
      <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type: none; display: none;">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
              <i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-stack-1x "></i>
            </span>
            Dashboard
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
              <i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-stack-1x "></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <a length="0" href="/PlayerPage/PlayerPage?userId=1&amp;universeId=1">Players</a> 
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
              <i class="fa fa-sort-amount-desc fa-stack-1x "></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <a length="0" href="/Ranking/Ranking?universeId=1">Rank</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
              <i class="fa fa-users fa-stack-1x "></i>
            </span>
            Head to Head
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
          <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-stack-1x "></i>
        </span>
        Tournaments
      </a>
      <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type: none;" id="tournaments">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
              <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-stack-1x "></i>
            </span>
            2015-S1
          </a>
          <ul id="submenu" class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type: none; display: none;">
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/1" style="">Open d'australie</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/2" style="">Kiev</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/3" style="">Dublin</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/4" style="">Casa Blanca</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/5" style="">Monte Carlo</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/6" style="">Roland Garros</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/7" style="">Auckland</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/8" style="">US Open</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/9" style="">Paris Bercy</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/10" style="">London World Tour Finals</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
              <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-stack-1x "></i>
            </span>
            2016-S1
          </a>
          <ul id="submenu" class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type: none;">
            <li class="current">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/11" style="color:#fff">Open d'australie</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/12" style="">Boston</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/13" style="">Toronto</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/14" style="">Casa Blanca</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/15" style="">Rome</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left" style="color:#fff">
                  <i class="fa fa-star fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/16" style="color:#fff">Roland Garros</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left" style="color:#fff">
                  <i class="fa fa-star fa-table-1x "></i>
                </span>
              </a>
              <a href="/Tournament/Tournament/17" style="color:#fff">Dublin</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
          <i class="fa fa-database fa-stack-1x "></i>
        </span>
        Admin
      </a>
      <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type: none; display: none;">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
              <i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-stack-1x "></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <a href="/Admin/ManageTournaments?Length=0" style="color:#fff">Manage Tournaments</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the original exemple it's there : http://seegatesite.com/create-simple-cool-sidebar-menu-with-bootstrap-3/

Comment: it is work https://jsfiddle.net/ehevshat/

Answer (score 0):

It Seems like you are not referecing jquery in your code please try add jquery on top of your script.Your script should be like this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>

 $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
 });

 $("#menu-toggle-2").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled-2");
 $('#menu ul').hide();
  });

function initMenu() {
 $('#menu ul').hide();

 var test = $('[id=submenu]')
 for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  var element = test[i];
  if ($(element).children('.current').length > 0) {
  $('#tournaments ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
  $(element).parent().slideDown('normal')
  }
 }

$('#menu ul').children('.current').parent().show();

 $('#menu li a').click(function() {
var checkElement = $(this).next();
if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
  return false;
}

if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible')) && checkElement.attr("id") != "submenu") {
  $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
  checkElement.slideDown('normal');
  return false;
}

if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible')) && checkElement.attr("id") == "submenu") {
  $('#tournaments ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
  checkElement.slideDown('normal');
  return false;
  }
 });
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
    initMenu();
   });
 </script>
```